# Silly question about system of inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming

I need a confirmation
Let's say I have a system of inequalities

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
Ax \leq b \\
x \geq 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ , $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$. $n \geq m$  Assume also that $A$ has full rank. Is it possible to manipulates the inequalities involved such that for $i = 1 \ldots m$ I have that $x_i$ is bounded (above or below) by $x_{i-1},...,x_0$? Something like

$$
a_{ii} x_i \leq C_i + \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} c_{ij}x_j
$$

My guess would be yes, because if the matrix has full rank I can apply the gaussian elimination, which would provide me a triangular system.

But I need a confirmation.

Comment: The first problem: nothing guarantees that this system of inequalities is compatible.

Comment: Compatible you mean "it doesn't have solutions"? If that is what you mean, then in my case it always have solutions.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: In practice my system, is derived from a problem I have that does have solution, it's just a reformulation of the problem what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The form you advocate,  $$a_{ii} x_i \leq \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} c_{ij}x_j$$
has no constants anymore. Now this is not going to be the general case. 
As a contradictive example, consider the simple special case where the matrix $A$ is diagonal. Then the bounds just read  $$a_{ii} x_i \leq b_i$$ which contradicts your form.

Besides that, there is also a **contructive answer to your question**. Your system of inequalities 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
Ax \leq b \\
x \geq 0
\end{array}
\right\}
$$
actually describe the feasible region of a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) and you will find abundant literature on  that, e.g. [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/msande310/lecture05.pdf). From the point of view of your question, the feasible region is a convex polytope which can always be described, using slack variables, in standard form as 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\tilde A \tilde x =  \tilde b \\
\tilde x \geq 0
\end{array}
\right\}
$$
where the "tilde" variables are the original variables, augmented by slack variables. See theorem 3.15 in [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cxg286/Math484_V1.pdf). So this answers your question (if you include slack variables) since with this theorem, you have the relation $\tilde A \tilde x =  \tilde b$ between the variables. You can then use Gaussian elimination (as you suggest) for the augmented set of equations and the augmented inequalities, see   Example
3.50 in [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cxg286/Math484_V1.pdf).

Comment: So adding the slack variables allows me to apply the Gaussian elimination.  But again, I was basically wondering if it is always possible to rewrite the system in such a way that $x_i$ is bounded by $x_j$ with $j<i$. You can assume the feasible region is bounded.

Comment: no it's not possible - see the first part of my answer. Also, the Gaussian elimination works on a system which again includes constants.

Comment: It can involve constants. (I'm changing the form I proposed)

Comment: I mean I did some computations that should show that is possible. However I need confirmation.

Comment: Again: it's NOT possible on the original variables x. Here is a counterexample. Suppose you have the full rank system $x + y \le 4$ and $x-y \le 2$, and $x\ge0$, $y \ge0$. The region is bounded. Just draw it to see what's going an. Applying Gaussian elimination directly, you add the two inequalities to obtain $x <3$. Now that's certainly true, but this inequality plus one inequality with 2 variables  do not lead to a description of the feasible region. For this description, you still need two inequalities with **both** variables.

Comment: --> Gaussian elimination works with equations. This is why you should move to the "tilde" system. Again, please follow the given links.